# Finding a program's installation path using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, search, directory

I've been working very hard on a now, very very long script. What I need to do is find the installation directory for a given piece of software. I was using

```
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG Query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{1779292D-1DAD-47E3-9404-8B32455264C2}\8.1e\HELPDIR" /ve 2^>nul') do set "ExeLoc=%%~b"
```

The problem with this is that it only works on the latest version of the software. Is there a way I can check the Programs and Features for an application, then grab the directory and set it to "ExeLoc"? And is there a way to do this without being too specific? For example, let's say "Program" is the application name, but in Programs and Features it may show up as "Program" or "Program Client" or "Program Version X.Y" or "Program Client Version X.Y". Would there be a way to search for "Starts with Program" then grab the path from there?

Let me know if you need further information from me.

Oh, and this needs to be within a batch file, without installing any additional API or other scripts, because it needs to be able to run on any machine on the fly, and we're not allowed to install additional software on machines.

Comment: Did you mean you want to search a program with wildcard character ?

Comment: `where /R %SystemDrive%\ filenamemask`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the help of the command **Where**

[image]

Try this batch that can accept wildcards with the command **Where.exe** as string input :

```
@echo off
Mode con cols=90 lines=15
set Location=C:\Program files
Set FileName=Program*
Set Tmp=Tmp.txt
Set SearchResult=SearchResult.txt
echo( & cls
echo(  & echo  Please Wait for moment .... Searching for "%FileName%" on "%Location%"
where /r "%Location%" "%FileName%" > %Tmp%
Cmd /U /C Type %Tmp% > %SearchResult%
Del %Tmp%
Start %SearchResult%
```

Comment: Will this also work if the "Program.exe" is out on the network within a non drive letter path? (\\server\folder\folder\Program.exe). When the directory is local, it'll be in one of 3 places, which I can test for, either C:\Program\Program.exe, C:\Program Files\Program\program.exe, or C:\Program Files (x86)\Program\program.exe.

I should have mentioned this before. My issue is mainly with older versions that allow the program binaries to be out on the network instead of on the local computer. This is the roadblock I've run into.